# I How to make a static tooltip in bootstrap 4

Tags: jquery, tooltip, bootstrap-4

On the Bootstrap web site there's a demonstration for static tooltips, I've copied the html generated to replicate the tooltip in my project but it didn't work.  Even though Bootstrap 4 is in development, the documentation could be much better.  [static tooltip](https://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/components/tooltips/#static-demo)

I've tried

```
<div  class="tooltip tooltip-right" role="tooltip"> <div class="tooltip-inner"> veicle code </div></div>
```

I added

Obs: The dynamic examples work.

Answer (score 0):

You could insert also JS code in page like this:

```
$(function () {
  $('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip()
})
```

and div could have this attribute

```
data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="Tooltip on top"
```

Comment: I don't want to show a tooltip. I want to style a div like a tooltip.

Answer (score 0):

You can try with Event Listeners that you can find on the Bootstrap Documentation.

```
<div class="container">

     <button id="myStaticTooltip" type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="bottom" title="Static Tooltip">
       Test
    </button>

</div>
```

And with this Jquery code :

```
$(function () {
  $('#myStaticTooltip').tooltip('toggle')
  $('#myStaticTooltip').on('hide.bs.tooltip', function () { return false;});
  $('#myStaticTooltip').on('show.bs.tooltip', function () { return false;});
})
```

Hope it can help.

Comment: Plus, if you want a `div` looking like a tooltip, you can modify this answer code by changing the `button` into an empty `span` element

Comment: This is a snippet with previous code : https://bootsnipp.com/snippets/nNM6z

Answer (score 0):

If the goal is to show a tooltip, and make it always visible:

For anyone getting here working with more recent versions of Bootstrap, on Bootstrap 5 you can just define the *trigger* as `manual`, and all mouse events will be ignored. Then, just `show` the tooltip when you want, and it will stay there (until you remove it using Javascript).

Example tooltip (using bootstrap 5):

```
<button id="example" type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-bs-toggle="tooltip" data-bs-placement="top" title="Tooltip on top" data-bs-trigger="manual">
  Example tooltip on button
</button>
```

Javascript:

```
var exampleBtn = document.getElementById('example');
var tooltip = new bootstrap.Tooltip(exampleBtn);
tooltip.show();
```

Answer (score -1):

You could try with this following code:

```
<div class="bd-example-tooltip-static">
    <div class="tooltip tooltip-top" role="tooltip">
        <div class="tooltip-inner">Tooltip on the top</div>
    </div>
    <div class="tooltip tooltip-right" role="tooltip">
       <div class="tooltip-inner">Tooltip on the right</div>
    </div>
    <div class="tooltip tooltip-bottom" role="tooltip">
        <div class="tooltip-inner">Tooltip on the bottom</div>
    </div>
    <div class="tooltip tooltip-left" role="tooltip">
       <div class="tooltip-inner">Tooltip on the left</div>
    </div>
</div>
```